# MySql query to check list of ids if they are friends with me?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a list of ids(userId's) that was found using a sql command that I want to check with my *friends* table to see if they are indeed friends with myself, a userid I will provide with, and have a column that will represent if they are and also group them if they are my friend and not my friend.

Example:

```
List of userids:
1
2
3
```

```
Friends table:
-------
userId           *the userid sending a friend request*
friendId         *the userid receiving the friend request*
relationshipId   *an unique id for the relationship*
initiated_by     *the userid initiating the friend request*
status           *whether or not the users are friends 'friends' or 'pending'*
```

[sample friends table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmGxo.png)

I tried creating a subquery that would first get the list of ids I want, and then tried to compare it with my friends table but couldn't quite put it together because the friends table is not bidirectional, meaning each row represents a relationship between 2 people with a status *friends* or *pending*

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to get the friend of a person (i.e. pick either the `userid` or the `friendid` from the `friends` table).

As of MySQL 8 you can use a `WITH` clause to get this readable:

```
with friends_of_user_1 as
(
  select case when userid = 1 then friendid else userid end as userid
  from friends
  where 1 in (userid, friendid)
  and status = 'friends'
)
, friends_of_user_2 as
(
  select case when userid = 2 then friendid else userid end as userid
  from friends
  where 2 in (userid, friendid)
  and status = 'friends'
)
select 
  userid,
  userid in (select userid from friends_of_user_2) as is_friend_of_user_2
from friends_of_user_1;
```

The same without `WITH`:

```
select 
  userid,
  userid in 
  (
    select case when userid = 2 then friendid else userid end as userid
    from friends
    where 2 in (userid, friendid)
    and status = 'friends'
  ) as is_friend_of_user_2
from 
(
  select case when userid = 1 then friendid else userid end as userid
  from friends
  where 1 in (userid, friendid)
  and status = 'friends'
) friends_of_user_1;
```

Comment: This example is close to what I am trying to recreate, the only issue is that this example isn't quite what im looking to do. I am trying to compare a list of user ids I obtain from another sql query (select userid from anothertable) and compare that with the friends table to check if they are friends with my user id.

Comment: So, it's not friends_of_user_1, but users_you_get_from_a_query. Same, same, I'd say. Just replace the subquery.

Comment: Awesome yeah I was able to fiddle around and get that to work! Is there a way to maybe change this around to use a join instead if possible? Concerned about the performance impact in using subqueries rather than joins.

Comment: Joins are not faster than subqueries. Always use the appropriate method for a task. This can be a join or an `IN` clause or an `EXISTS` clause or something else. Don't use joins without considering whether this is the appropriate approach - quite often they are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all friends bidirectional, i.e. (a,b), (b,a), (a,c), (c,a), ... with a `UNION` query. If it is guaranteed that there exists no (b,a) in the table when there exists (a,b), then you can use `UNION ALL`, otherwise use `UNION`.

Then you can aggregate per user and see whether they are friends with user 1 and/or user 2:

```
with all_friends as
(
  select userid as userid1, friendid as userid2 from friends status = 'friends'
  union
  select friendid as userid1, userid as userid2 from friends status = 'friends'
)
select
  userid1,
  sum(userid2 = 2) > 0 as is_friends_with_user_2
from all_friends
group by userid1
having sum(userid2 = 1) > 0 -- is friends with user 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the alias of Friends a second time to get the reciprocal relationship

```
  SELECT A.Name,...
  FROM Users A
  JOIN friends FA ON A.userID = FA.userID
  LEFT JOIN friends FB ON FA.friedID = FB.userID
  JOIN Users B on FB.userID = B.userID
  ...
```

So `FA` is the friends of `A` and `FB` is the friend relationship of `B` back to `A`.